# Backup Client Computers using Windows Server or a NAS?

Tags: networking, backup, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, network-attached-storage

Not sure whether this is the right community to ask this question, so sorry if it's the wrong one!*

Which option should (or is recommended) you use to make a backup of multiple computers (like 24-30 computers) within a business network using either a random NAS or any version of Windows Server 2012 running "Essentials Experience"?

- All computers runs Windows 7, and it's just backing up the files on the computers most times, and sometimes the entire system. If that's some useful information for some reason.

Like, what are the pros and cons over the other?

(sorry for my very lousy and poorly formulated question!)

Thanks in advance! =)

Answer (score 7):

We are using Veeam generally over the whole company's infrastructure and it works great for a years. AFAIR you can even use free version.
https://www.veeam.com/free-virtualization-software-vmware-hyper-v.html

Comment: Veeam is a good backup solution, I agree. We're using Starwind on two servers and backup our VMs with Veeam to cloud, some of the VMs we need to recover once a week. All works great.